# im using Mongoose to try and push a objectId to an nestedArray inside a nestedArray inside a document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So i've search for a solution, tryed multi types of codes but cant add the newObjectId to the list inside the nestedArray in the document.

im also using $in to compare the value to a list, and that way update multi objects with the same value as well i have there multiple objects in the nestedArray

1st try:

```
Chat.updateMany({ _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(documentId), 
                    'nestedArray._id': { $in: listOfIds } },
                  {$push: { "nestedArray.$.list": newId }},
                  {"multi": true}

                  ).exec();
```

2nd try:

```
Chat.updateMany({'nestedArray._id':  { $in: listOfIds }},
{$addToSet: { "messages.$.list": newId }})
```

i was expecting to have a new objectId in the list

Comment: Please provide sample input and output documents

Comment: I agree that we need more information here to assist, the values of the variables being passed to the commands as well. Overall it's not clear to me what you're asking for - but I do have one observation. You're using `updateMany` and reference "_update multi objects_" in the question. But the query to the command has an equality filter on the `_id` field which is a unique field in MongoDB. Therefore the command can only modify a single document at most